# Sending and receiving an Object from an RMI Server and Client using seralization

Tags: java, serialization, rmi

I was implementing a banking system and I want to send a `ResultSet` to the client.  But Java shows me an error.

```
    public interface SekelatonInterface extends Remote {

    public String test() throws RemoteException; // this is ok it works fine

    public ConnectionClass getConnection() throws RemoteException; //shows error on     client call

     public ResultSet getAllDeposits(Integer CustomerId) throws RemoteException;
  }

  public class SekelatonImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements SekelationInterface {



   SekelatonImpl() throws RemoteException{

   }

              //sekelaton implemeation
    public ConnectionClass getConnection() {

    try {
     dbobject = new ConnectionClass();
      dbobject.connectDb();
     dbObject.setQuery("select * from cutomer"); 
      return dbobject; //this method is on connection class ,dont be confuse

     }

     catch(Exception ex)

           {

        System.out.println("Error :"+ex.getMessage());
           }

    }

  }

   public class Server {


   public  void PackServerandRun(String SecurityFilePath,Integer port,String rmiUrl) {


   //do rmi registery stuff and run server
    SekelatonImpl  databaseObject = new SekelationImpl(); // rebind this object

    }

}
    cleintstub.test(); //this recive the server message or works fine
    cleintStub.getConnection(); //why couldn't i get a ConnectionClass Object ?
```

When I run client the error I'm seeing is:

> Registry Look Up has error Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: java.io.EOFException

Comment: and what is the error? Post the stacktrace

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK i will attempt to answer my own question after i have gone through some research i have solved the problems.

the error was sending un-serialized object.

Since,ResultSet Doesn't support Serialization i have also created a Model class and Return
List of the model class object to the client.By adding Serialization to every class you want to transfer as parameter ,and also including your skeleton implementation serialization ,Note that all the class need to be defined on client side.

```
 public class ConnectionClass implements java.io.Serializable {

 }

public interface SekelatonInterface extends Remote ,java.io.Serializable{

public Login getTestClass()throws RemoteException;

public String test() throws RemoteException;

public List<Login> getConnection() throws RemoteException;

public void sayHitoServer(String messages) throws RemoteException;

}
public class SkeletonInterfaceImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements      SekelatonInterface,Serializable {

  //implement all your skeleton methods
 }

 //this to change result set into model class to transefer it to client

public class Login {

private int Id;

private String Username;

private String Password;

public Login() {

}

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int Id) {
    this.Id = Id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return Username;
}

public void setUsername(String Username) {
    this.Username = Username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String Password) {
    this.Password = Password;
}

public Login(ResultSet resultset){
    try{
    // resultset.next();
  Id = resultset.getInt("LoginId");
  Username =resultset.getString("Uname");
  Password = resultset.getString("Password");
          }
    catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Setting Up Login"+ex.getMessage());

     }
   }
}
```

ALl the above method will work just fine.But,the problem here is i want to bind the list of model class to a jtable model.how can i pass columns suitable for TableModel ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to send a `ResultSet`

Bad luck, you can't. `ResultSet` isn't `Serializable`.

> or connection object to the client ,actually the later is no good idea.

It is not only not a 'good idea', it is a completely meaningless idea. You can't send a telephone over a telephone wire. Similarly you can't send a connection over another connection. Let alone the fact that `Connection` isn't `Serializable` either.

> But, Java shows me an error.

Next time you post a problem report, anywhere, make sure to include the *actual problem,* including the error message, *verbatim,* cut-and-pasted, not manually transcribed, along with the relevant section of source code, a line number indication if necessary, and the expected and actual outputs.

```
catch(){
   }
```

*Never* ignore an exception. Otherwise you turn debugging into a mere guessing game.

Comment: Ok,Thank you! but what do u suggest to send a result of a database actually how to return not the result set itself but how to make it serializable ?

Comment: You could create a `Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>>` from your `ResultSet`, indexed by unique key at the outer level and column name at the inner level; or you could have a look at creating `WebRowSet` and creating an XML document from it, and returning that as a String; but this is a poor use of RMI in my humble opinion. You should keep the data at the server and just provide